# What differences between redirect withInput() or just back() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm wondering how `withInput()` works in laravel, because if I look inside the code it populate data to flash session, then I tried just `redirect()->back()` and i could retrieve the old input with `old()` helper, so why I need include `withInput()` if I didn't filter some inputs must be flashed or not eg. `redirect()->withInput($request->only('email'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting with `back()` redirects the user back to the previous page, with user input (as laravel saves this as flash data).

The `withInput()` can be used if you want to redirect the user with input, and not necessarily back. For example, I can redirect the user to a different page, with user input intact: `redirect('stage2')->withInput()`, i.e. if I have a 2 step registration process.

Comment: that the things i want to know,, `withInput()` useful in that situation, so i could remove if i dont need because `back()` automatic flashing all data right? thanks,,

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Redirect:**

This one is pretty straightforward – so if, for example, your website is www.website.com, it would redirect a user to the main URL + whatever you say in the parameter:

return redirect('homepage');
Redirects to http://www.website.com/homepage

return redirect('auth/login');
Redirects to www.website.com/auth/login

return redirect('');
Redirects to the main page – www.website.com

**Chaining Methods and Redirecting Back:**

If you just want to redirect a user back to the previous page (the most common example – is to redirect back to the form page after data validation failed), you can use this:

return redirect()->back();

As you see in this example, you can add more methods to redirect() – even more than one, we’ll see that in the next example.

Redirect with Data:

There are two methods which allow to send some data with the redirect. Firstly, you can just use with():

return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');
This code will add an item to the Session Flash Data, with key “error” and value “Something went wrong” – and then you can use that in the result Controller or View as session(‘error’).

Comment: my question is if I redirect()->back()->withInput() or i redirect()->back() this approach return same result isn't ? i cound get old data with old() helper, then if i fail in validation i just  use redirect()->back() enough right?

Comment: You should use ```withInput()``` as that how Laravel handles redirection when validation fails.